# Add Visual Web Part SharePoint server 2010 (add url server)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, visual-studio

I have access at the site collections administrator level SharePoint server 2010 Ent, but no one will give me access to the server, only from the workstation, how to be?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal, You can not develop SharePoint solutions (`Server Side Object Model`) without having SharePoint installed on your local machine.

> Only the SharePoint Add-ins is supported in the remote development.

**The available workarounds,**

- Create a new SharePoint environment for development purpose, then let the SharePoint Administrator deploy WSP solution to your destination environment.
- Check this workaround (**Not tried**) [Develop SharePoint Solutions without installing SharePoint on Visual Studio](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/sharepoint-pitfalls-creating-a-visual-studio-project-without-sharepoint-locally-installed)
- Work with SharePoint Addins via`Client-Side Object Model` or `JavaScript Object Model`. For more details check [Develop SharePoint Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/develop-sharepoint-add-ins)